# How to change dialog color dynamically? - Bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, bootbox

To change the text in [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) dialog, I use `<span id='someID'></span>` and then use jQuery as follow: `$("#someID").text("The new Text");`

The problem I am facing is how to change the dialog color?

Inside my dialog I have the following (to set the dialog color):

```
className: "modal-danger nonumpad",
```

I want to change the class name to `modal-success nonumpad` when an action takes place.

Here is my code:

```
callDialog = bootbox.dialog({
    className: "modal-danger nonumpad", // the class I want to change
    closeButton: false,
    animate: true,
    title: 'Making Call',
    message: '<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i><span id="test"> Waiting for Reply... </span></div>',
    onEscape: null,
    buttons: {
        hangup: {
            label: "<span id='hangup' <i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Cancel </span>",
            className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
            callback: function(){
                $("#dynamicMsg").text("This is dynamic msg");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});

callDialog.init(function(){
    peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
        conn.on('data', function(data){
    // Will print 'hi!'
        call = data;
        console.log(call);
        if(call == "ACCEPT"){
            $("#test").text("This is dynamic msg");
            $("#hangup").text("Hangup");
        } else {

        }
    });
    });
});
```

How can I change the `className` inside the `init()` function?

**NOTE:**  `<span id='someID'></span>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a reference to your dialog, something like this should work, using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
callDialog.find('.modal-danger').toggleClass('modal-danger modal-success');
```

This will find the child element with the class `modal-danger`, and then remove it while adding the class `modal-success`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution, it didn't solve it for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$("#someID").removeClass('modal-danger').addClass('modal-success');
```

The someID will have to be the ID of your dialog. Or, if you have multiple or it's dynamic, reference a class name instead.

```
$(".someClass").removeClass('modal-danger').addClass('modal-success');
```

Comment: can you please guide what to replace `someID` with? because the way i am creating the the dialog is different as it is shown in the question with no ID

Answer (score 0):

> can you please guide what to replace someID with? because the way i am
>   creating the the dialog is different as it is shown in the question
>   with no ID

Answering your comment question, your should replace it with whatever individual selector you have for the element you want to change. If is just one element you sould think about giving it an ID. Depending on where you are calling that, you can define your selector by the `event.currentTarget`, or if at that moment there is only this element with those classes `"modal-danger nonumpad"`, you can use it as a selector too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: 
`$(callDialog).removeClass('modal-danger').addClass('modal-success');`

The `$(callDialog)` selects the variable that the bootbox dialog object was assigned to and turns it to a [JQuery Object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

The `.removeClass('modal-danger')` is a [JQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove the class passed as a parameter from the selected object.

The `.addClass('modal-success')`  is also a [JQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) used to add the class passed as a parameter to the selected object.

Comment: Please explain your code, so it's easier to understand.